# Azure AD Powershell : Grant consent failed with error: Application is requesting permissions that are either invalid or out of date

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create an Azure AD app with Application and Delegated permissions set for O365 API. The script works fine but when I try to grant consent from Azure portal. It shows below error :

*Grant consent failed with error: Application '5a61ff93-7076-44a7-980f-d40def08ee9b' is requesting permissions that are either invalid or out of date. [wyvzL7hZM8VOZFL0Sv4kCF]*

The permissions guids are correct. Actually the issue is setting the Application type permissions. The delegated/OAuth2 permissions can be granted consent without any error.

As you see, the permissions are set (both Application and Delegated :
[image: Configured permissions]

But upon granting consent, I see the below error  :

[image]

```
# This script creates a new Azure AD application 
and sets the Application and Delegated permissions for specific API (O365)

$Connection = Connect-AzureAD

$CurrentDateTime = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%m-%S"
$ApplicationDisplayName = "Splunk Office 365 App_" +$CurrentDateTime
#  Get the service principal for O365 and Microsoft Graph
$ServicePrincipalO365API        = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Office 365 Management APIs" }

# Get all application permissions for O365 API
$ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRoles = $ServicePrincipalO365API.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -match "\bActivityReports.Read\b|\bActivityFeed.ReadDlp\b|\bServiceHealth.Read\b"}

# Get all delegated permissions for O365 API
$ServicePrincipalO365APIDelegatedRoles = $ServicePrincipalO365API.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object {$_.Value -match "\bActivityReports.Read\b|\bActivityFeed.ReadDlp\b|\bServiceHealth.Read\b"}

# Create a Required Resource Access object for Office 365
$RequiredResourceAccessO365API = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$RequiredResourceAccessO365API.ResourceAppId = $ServicePrincipalO365API.AppId

$ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRolesSelectedPermissions = @()


# Get all the Resource Access objects for the Application permissions
foreach ($ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRole in $ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRoles)
{
    $Permission = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList $ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRole.Id,"Role"
    $ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRolesSelectedPermissions += $Permission
}


# Get all the Resource Access objects for the Delegated permissions
foreach ($ServicePrincipalO365APIDelegatedRole in $ServicePrincipalO365APIDelegatedRoles)
{
    $Permission = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList $ServicePrincipalO365APIDelegatedRole.Id,"Scope"
    $ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRolesSelectedPermissions += $Permission

}

# Assign all the permissions to the required Resource access for the O365 API 
$RequiredResourceAccessO365API.ResourceAccess  = $ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRolesSelectedPermissions

# Create the Password credential for the new app
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$ApplicationPassword =[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(32,2)
$ApplicationPassword = $ApplicationPassword.Replace("+","_")
$ApplicationPassword = $ApplicationPassword.Replace("-","_")
$keyId = (New-Guid).ToString();
$fromDate = [System.DateTime]::Now
$durationInYears = 5
$endDate = $fromDate.AddYears($durationInYears) 
$Applicationkey = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordCredential($null, $endDate, $keyId, $fromDate, $ApplicationPassword)

# Create the new app with the password cred
$aadApplication = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $ApplicationDisplayName -PasswordCredentials $Applicationkey

write-output("Application created")

# Set the permissions
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $aadApplication.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $RequiredResourceAccessO365API
write-output("Application permissions set")
```

**EDIT**

I add the application permissions to a list and assign to a type "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess":

$RequiredResourceAccessO365API.ResourceAccess  = $ServicePrincipalO365APIAppRolesSelectedPermissions

But  "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess", ResourceAccess Property takes only OAuth i.e. Delegated permissions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.graph.rbac.fluent.models.requiredresourceaccess.resourceaccess?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-management-graph-rbac-fluent-models-requiredresourceaccess-resourceaccess

So how one can add the application permissions to it? Is this why I'm not able to grant consent for application permissions?
Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same error in my environment. I have created an Azure AD application and granted the same permissions using your PowerShell script.***

I got same error while trying to grant admin consent as below:

[image]

> **`ActivityReports.Read`** API permission is used to read activity reports of your organization.

Before adding this permission, you need to **enable Audit Logs in Office365**.
Check whether that permission is enabled or not like below:

[image]

[image]

If you try to grant admin consent without enabling this, you will get that error.

I tried removing **`ActivityReports.Read`** permission(both Application and Delegated) and granted admin consent successfully like below:

[image]

If you need **`ActivityReports.Read`**  permission, **add it after turning on Audit Logs for Office365.**

To know how to enable that option in detail, make use of below links:

[Turn auditing on or off - Microsoft Purview | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/turn-audit-log-search-on-or-off?view=o365-worldwide#verify-the-auditing-status-for-your-organization)

[How to enable and configure Office 365 logging and auditing - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYxmt-R21Sg&t=104s)